# Having a problem with Substance Painter or UV. Only some fragments of unwraped UVs are working ok

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv

[image: Blender View]

[image: Substance Painter View]

Hello! I'm having a problem with UVs in Blender.

I made this little handgun model, unwrapped it a lot of times to make it work, but unsuccessful. When i exported the model as .fbx file and loaded it inside Substance Painter, all the UV maps turned out grey as you can see on second screenshot. Of course I can only draw on some correctly working UV islands on the right and nowhere else.

I have no idea what i could do wrong, because it's literally my first model in Blender.

I have tried connecting parts of the mesh with boolean modifier, making different seams before unwrapping, changing position of UVs islands in the UV editor of Blender, as well as giving every part of the mesh its own material.

Comment: In Edit mode, please make sure there is no Hidden face (Alt+H). Then check your UV again. My guess is one or more faces are taking the whole UV space.

Comment: @thibsert, i've tryed this again and couldn't find any hidden faces. 
Maybe something happened because i dissolved some edges? I had like two strange lines (edges) going through my bottom and top part of the gun for no reason.

Comment: Hi :) I'm not a Substance Painter user (yet) but ........... Check out this short tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RydSV0lKfHI&feature=emb_rel_end  At 5:00 looks like your problem. In the second video is explained one method to overcome this. ( at 4:05 )   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhKQiuzQipg